# Внутренний vs Анонимный vs Отдельный классы

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

В ходе изучения языка все реже возникают вопросы "Как решить задачу?" и все чаще встает вопрос "Какой способ более правильный с точки зрения хорошего тона программирования?"

К примеру, в ходе написания программы, реализующей возможность ведения складского учета, возник вопрос, какой класс использовать: анонимный, внешний или внутренний? Есть класс главного окна программы, реализующий `JDesktopPane`. Есть отдельный класс "Каталог товаров", реализующий `JInternalFrame`. Из последнего, нажатием кнопок, открывается окно Карточки товара" (также класс `extends JInternalFrame`). В свою очередь кликом по кнопкам он реализует открытие окон выбора группы товара, единицы измерения, категории и т.д. Все это тоже `JInternalFrame`.

Вот теперь стоит вопрос, какой тип класса "эстетичнее" использовать? Логика подсказывает делать все классы ниже "Каталога товаров" вложенными в него, а все слушатели нажатия кнопок - анонимными. Но тогда класс получается под тысячу строк кода, что влияет на читаемость. Или это нормально? В общем я как тот осел, между двумя стогами сена.

Вот, к примеру, такой участок кода. Оптимален ли он, или стоит изменить структуру?

```
package catalogs;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import main.Global;

/**
 * Класс окна справочника товара. Выводит окно каталога товаров с возможностью добавления/удаления/редактирования групп товаров и самих
 * товаров. Представляет собой древо групп товаров, таблицу товаров, кнопки добавления/удаления/редактирования.
 */              

public class ProductCatalog extends JInternalFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JDesktopPane mainPane;
    public JTree treeGroup;
    private GroupTreeModel treeGroupModel;
    private JScrollPane treeGroupScrlPane;
    private JButton btnAddGroup;
    private JButton btnDelGroup;
    private JButton btnEditGroup;
    public JTable tblProduct;
    public ProdTableModel tblProductModel;
    private JScrollPane tblProductScrlPane;
    private JButton btnAddProduct;
    private JButton btnDelProduct;
    private JButton btnEditProduct;

/**
 * Конструктор, принимает ссылку на JDesctopPane главного окна.
 */
    public ProductCatalog(JDesktopPane mainPane){
        this.mainPane = mainPane;       
        paintComponents();      
    }

/**
 * Метод отрисовки компонент окна.
 */
    private void paintComponents(){
        treeGroupModel = new GroupTreeModel();
        treeGroup = new JTree(treeGroupModel);
        treeGroup.setSelectionRow(0);
        treeGroup.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent selection) {
                if(!treeGroup.isSelectionEmpty()){
                    tblProductModel.buildTable(treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
                    tblProduct.revalidate();
                    tblProduct.repaint();
                }           
            }
        });
        treeGroupScrlPane = new JScrollPane(treeGroup);
        treeGroupScrlPane.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 260);

        btnAddGroup = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnAddGroupIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnAddGroup.png");
        btnAddGroup.setIcon(btnAddGroupIcon);
        btnAddGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addGroup();             
            }           
        });
        btnAddGroup.setBounds(10, 280, 30, 30);
        btnDelGroup = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnDelGroupIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnDelGroup.png");
        btnDelGroup.setIcon(btnDelGroupIcon);
        btnDelGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delGroup();         
            }           
        });
        btnDelGroup.setBounds(50, 280, 30, 30);     
        btnEditGroup = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnEditGroupIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnEditGroup.png");
        btnEditGroup.setIcon(btnEditGroupIcon);
        btnEditGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editGroup();                
            }           
        });
        btnEditGroup.setBounds(90, 280, 30, 30);

        tblProductModel = new ProdTableModel();
        tblProduct = new JTable(tblProductModel);
        tblProductModel.buildTable(treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
        tblProduct.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        tblProduct.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        tblProduct.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tblProduct.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
        tblProduct.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        tblProduct.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(25);
        tblProduct.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblProductScrlPane = new JScrollPane(tblProduct);
        tblProductScrlPane.setBounds(170, 10, 500, 260);

        btnAddProduct = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnAddProductIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnAddProduct.png");
        btnAddProduct.setIcon(btnAddProductIcon);
        btnAddProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addProduct();           
            }           
        });
        btnAddProduct.setBounds(170, 280, 30, 30);
        btnDelProduct = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnDelProductIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnDelProduct.png");
        btnDelProduct.setIcon(btnDelProductIcon);
        btnDelProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delProduct();           
            }           
        });
        btnDelProduct.setBounds(210, 280, 30, 30);
        btnEditProduct = new JButton();
        ImageIcon btnEditProductIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnEditProduct.png");
        btnEditProduct.setIcon(btnEditProductIcon);
        btnEditProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editProduct();          
            }           
        });
        btnEditProduct.setBounds(250, 280, 30, 30);

        this.setTitle("Каталог товаров");
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener(){
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                treeGroupScrlPane.setBounds(10, 10, 150, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-87);
                btnAddGroup.setBounds(10, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
                btnDelGroup.setBounds(50, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
                btnEditGroup.setBounds(90, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
                tblProductScrlPane.setBounds(170, 10, ProductCatalog.this.getWidth()-200, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-87);
                btnAddProduct.setBounds(170, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
                btnDelProduct.setBounds(210, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
                btnEditProduct.setBounds(250, ProductCatalog.this.getHeight()-67, 30, 30);
            }
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
        });
        this.setClosable(true);
        this.setMaximizable(true);
        this.setIconifiable(true);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(700, 347);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(treeGroupScrlPane);
        this.add(btnAddGroup);
        this.add(btnDelGroup);
        this.add(btnEditGroup);
        this.add(tblProductScrlPane);
        this.add(btnAddProduct);
        this.add(btnDelProduct);
        this.add(btnEditProduct);
    }

/**
 * Рекурсивный метод построения массива элементов древа групп товаров.
 */
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> getComboBoxTree(Object parent, String separator){      
        Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+parent+"'");
        for(int i=0; i<buf.length; i++){
            if(parent.toString().equals("0")) 
                arr.add(separator+buf[i][1].toString());
            else arr.add(separator+buf[i][1].toString());
            Object[][] buf2 = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+buf[i][0]+"'");
            if(buf2.length>0) getComboBoxTree(buf[i][0], "   "+separator);
        }   
        return arr;
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий добавление группы товаров в БД.
 */
    private void addGroup(){
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Введите название новой подгруппы\n в группе \""+ treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"\":", "");
        if(name!=null){
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ name +"'");
            if(buf.length==0){
                if(name.length()>0){
                    Object[][] parentGroup = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"'");
                    Global.sqlQueryVoid("INSERT INTO `prod_group` (`name`, `parent`) VALUES ('"+ name +"', '"+ parentGroup[0][0] +"')");
                    treeGroup.updateUI();
                }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Наименование группы товаров не может быть пустым!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Группа товаров с таким наименованием уже существует!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                
        }
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий удаление группы товаров из БД.
 */
    private void delGroup(){
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"'");
        Object[][] buf2 = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `group`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
        Object[][] buf3 = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
        if(buf2.length==0 && buf3.length==0) isEmpty = true;
        if(!treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent().equals(null)){     //Если выделена группа, 
            if(isEmpty){                                                    //она пуста 
                if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Вы уверены?", "Подтверждение удаления", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==0){ //и мы подтверждаем удаление, тогда удаляем.
                    Global.sqlQueryVoid("DELETE FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent() +"'");
                    treeGroup.updateUI();
                }
            }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Нельзя удалить эту папку, т.к. она не пуста!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
        }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Вы не выбрали ни одну папку!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий редактирование группы товаров в БД.
 */
    private void editGroup(){

        if(treeGroup.getSelectionRows()[0] != 0){           //Если выбрана не корневая группа, переименовываем группу товаров.
            final JInternalFrame ifEditGroup;
            final JComboBox<String> cbParent;       
            final JLabel lblName;       
            final JTextField tfName;
            final JButton btnOK;
            final JButton btnCancel;            
            final ArrayList<String> arr;

            ifEditGroup = new JInternalFrame();

            JLabel lblParent = new JLabel("Родительская группа:");
            lblParent.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 20);
            cbParent = new JComboBox<String>();
            cbParent.setBounds(170, 10, 250, 20);
            arr = getComboBoxTree(0, "");
            for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
                cbParent.addItem(arr.get(i));
            }
            String group = ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
            String parentID = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `parent` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+group+"'")[0][0].toString();
            String parentName = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `name` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `id`='"+parentID+"'")[0][0].toString();
            for(int i=0; i<cbParent.getItemCount(); i++){
                if (cbParent.getItemAt(i).toString().trim().equals(parentName)) cbParent.setSelectedIndex(i);
            }
            lblName = new JLabel("Наименование группы:");
            lblName.setBounds(10, 40, 150, 20);
            tfName = new JTextField();
            tfName.setText(ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString());
            tfName.setBounds(170, 40, 250, 20);
            btnOK = new JButton("Сохранить");
            ImageIcon btnOKIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnOK.png");
            btnOK.setIcon(btnOKIcon);
            btnOK.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            btnOK.setBounds(250, 70, 80, 20);
            btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String groupCode = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent()+"'")[0][0].toString();
                    String parentCode = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+cbParent.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()+"'")[0][0].toString();
                    Global.sqlQueryVoid("UPDATE `prod_group` SET `parent`='"+parentCode+"' WHERE `id`='"+groupCode+"'");        
                    Global.sqlQueryVoid("UPDATE `prod_group` SET `name`='"+tfName.getText()+"' WHERE `id`='"+groupCode+"'");
                    ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.updateUI();
                    arr.clear();
                    ifEditGroup.dispose();
                }               
            });
            btnCancel = new JButton("Назад");
            ImageIcon btnCancelIcon = new ImageIcon(Global.getAppPath()+File.separator+"images"+File.separator+"btnCancel.png");
            btnCancel.setIcon(btnCancelIcon);
            btnCancel.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            btnCancel.setBounds(340, 70, 80, 20);
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ifEditGroup.dispose();                  
                }               
            });         

            ifEditGroup.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            ifEditGroup.add(lblParent);
            ifEditGroup.add(cbParent);
            ifEditGroup.add(lblName);
            ifEditGroup.add(tfName);
            ifEditGroup.add(btnOK);
            ifEditGroup.add(btnCancel);
            ifEditGroup.setTitle("Редактирование группы товаров");
            ifEditGroup.setSize(450, 130);
            ifEditGroup.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            ifEditGroup.setVisible(true);   

            boolean isOpened = false;
            Object[] ifArr = mainPane.getAllFrames();
            for(int i=0; i<ifArr.length; i++){
                if(ifArr[i].toString().contains("Редактирование группы товаров")) isOpened = true;
            }
            if(!isOpened){
                mainPane.add(ifEditGroup);
                ifEditGroup.setLocation((mainPane.getWidth()-ifEditGroup.getWidth())/2, (mainPane.getHeight()-ifEditGroup.getHeight())/2);
                ifEditGroup.toFront();
                try {
                    ifEditGroup.setSelected(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {}
            }                   
        }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Нельзя переименовать корневую группу!", "Ошибка!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий добавление товара в БД.
 */
    private void addProduct(){
        boolean isOpened = false;
        Object[] ifArr = mainPane.getAllFrames();
        for(int i=0; i<ifArr.length; i++){
            if(ifArr[i].toString().contains("Карточка товара")) isOpened = true;
        }
        if(!isOpened){
            ProductCard prodCard = new ProductCard(mainPane, ProductCatalog.this);
            mainPane.add(prodCard);
            prodCard.setLocation((mainPane.getWidth()-prodCard.getWidth())/2, (mainPane.getHeight()-prodCard.getHeight())/2);
            prodCard.toFront();
            try {
                prodCard.setSelected(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {}
            String group = ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
            for(int i=0; i<prodCard.cbGroup.getItemCount(); i++){
                if (prodCard.cbGroup.getItemAt(i).toString().trim().equals(group)) prodCard.cbGroup.setSelectedIndex(i);
            }
        }   
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий удаление товара из БД.
 */
    private void delProduct(){
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Вы уверены?", "Подтверждение удаления", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==0){
            String code = ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            Global.sqlQueryVoid("DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `id`='"+code+"'");
            Global.sqlQueryVoid("DELETE FROM `prod_barcode` WHERE `prod_id`='"+code+"'");
            ProductCatalog.this.tblProductModel.buildTable(ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent());
            ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.revalidate();
            ProductCatalog.this.repaint();
        }       
    }

/**
 * Метод, реализующий редактирование товара в БД.
 */
    private void editProduct(){
        boolean isOpened = false;
        Object[] arr = mainPane.getAllFrames();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i].toString().contains("ProductCard")) isOpened = true;
        }
        if(!isOpened && ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow()!=-1){
            ProductCard prodCard = new ProductCard(mainPane, ProductCatalog.this);
            mainPane.add(prodCard);
            prodCard.setLocation((mainPane.getWidth()-prodCard.getWidth())/2, (mainPane.getHeight()-prodCard.getHeight())/2);
            prodCard.toFront();
            try {
                prodCard.setSelected(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {}   
            String code = ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            String group = ProductCatalog.this.treeGroup.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
            String name = ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
            String unit = ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
            Object[][] catId = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `category` FROM `product` WHERE `id`='"+code+"'");
            String category = "";
            if(catId[0][0]!=null) category = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `name` FROM `prod_category` WHERE `id`='"+catId[0][0]+"'")[0][0].toString();
            String comment = "";
            if(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 3)!=null) comment = ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getValueAt(ProductCatalog.this.tblProduct.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();                 
            prodCard.tfCode.setText(code);
            prodCard.tfName.setText(name);
            for(int i=0; i<prodCard.cbGroup.getItemCount(); i++){
                if (prodCard.cbGroup.getItemAt(i).toString().trim().equals(group)) prodCard.cbGroup.setSelectedIndex(i);
            }
            prodCard.cbUnit.setSelectedItem(unit);
            prodCard.cbCategory.setSelectedItem(category);
            prodCard.taComments.setText(comment);
        }       
    }

/**
 * Модель дерева.
 */
    private class GroupTreeModel implements TreeModel{
        @Override
        public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            return res[index][1];
        }
        @Override
        public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            return res.length;
        }
        @Override
        public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ parent +"'");
            Object parentCode = buf[0][0];
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='"+ parentCode +"'");
            int index = 0;
            for(int i =0; i<res.length; i++){
                if(res[i][1].equals(child)) index = i;
            }
            return index;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getRoot() {
            Object[][] res = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT * FROM `prod_group` WHERE `parent`='0'");
            return res[0][1];
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Object arg0) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath arg0, Object arg1) {}      
    }


/**
 * Модель таблицы.
 */
    public class ProdTableModel implements TableModel{
        private Object[][] sample = null;

        public void buildTable(Object group){           //Метод построения двумерного массива данных, на основе которого отрисовывается таблица товаров.
            Object[][] buf = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `id` FROM `prod_group` WHERE `name`='"+ group +"'");
            sample = Global.sqlQueryResult("SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`name`, `prod_unit`.`short_name`, `product`.`comments` "
                    + "FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `prod_unit` ON `product`.`unit`=`prod_unit`.`id`"
                    + " WHERE `product`.`group`='"+ buf[0][0] +"'");
        }       
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colInd) {
            return String.class;
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int colInd) {
            String colName ="";
            switch(colInd){
                case 0: colName = "Код"; break;
                case 1: colName = "Наименование"; break;
                case 2: colName = "Ед. изм."; break;
                case 3: colName = "Комментарий"; break;
            }
            return colName;
        }
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return sample.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowInd, int colInd) {
            return sample[rowInd][colInd];
        }
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {return false;}
        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {}      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Анонимные классы удобны там, где цель существования типа - применение
  в одной единственной точке на всё приложение.
- Внутренний (нестатический) класс существует внутри внешнего и может
  быть там скрыт. Кроме того сам имеет доступ к скрытому состоянию
  родителя.

Если такие "суперспособности" не принесут ощутимой пользы, то стоит склоняться к отдельным классам.

- Отдельные классы читаются лучше (и соответствуют Single
  responsibility) при прочих равных.

*А вообще, это достаточно тонкая грань между хорошим кодом и плохим. Чувство прекрасного развивается при чтении чужого кода, где ты распутывая клубок алгоритма подмечаешь для себя какие-то элегантные решения и злишься на излишнюю запутанность других.*

Comment: А слушатели нажатия кнопок тоже правильнее выделять в отдельный класс? Просто тогда проект быстро разрастается до невменяемых размеров.

Comment: @Artik Если слушатели у вас созданы для одного-единственного события одного объекта, то их вполне можно сделать анонимными типами. Представьте, что вы читаете код впервые, быстро ли вы разберетесь с ним? И проект не разрастается, суммарное количество кода будет примерно такое же. Пользуйтесь пакетами, разбивайте независимые подсистемы на самодостаточные модули, подключаемые через интерфейс. Модуляризация - это круто!

Comment: Спасибо. Многого еще не знаю. Т.е., как я понял, если по нажатию одной кнопки должен создаваться экземпляр класса окна и больше ничего, то его правильнее реализовать анонимным классом? А если на форме с десяток кнопок, которые должны создавать экземпляры окон, лучше тоже использовать анонимные классы слушателей для каждой кнопки или вынести их в один отдельный?

Comment: @Artik Если лиснеры работают подобно, то эту функциональность лучше выделить в отдельный или базовый класс.

Comment: Базовый, в смысле "оберточный"? И еще, Вы подсказали простую и умную мысль об обучении стилю на чужом коде. Не подскажете, где можно найти исходники достаточно профессиональных примеров?

Comment: @Artik Честно говоря, я не знаю, что можно посоветовать начинающему. Можно посмотреть какую-нибудь популярную софтинку на гитхабе. Но тут, как неумеющего плавать выбрасывать заборт: если поплывет (разберется), то будет мастером, если нет... то ничего не потеряет, в принципе.

Comment: @Artik Нет, базовый - в смысле базовый. Если у них есть общая функциональность, то  она оформляется как отдельный класс. Если есть какая-то специфика, то от этого класса наследуют и (пере)определяют новое поведение.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за наглость, но не могли бы Вы по свободе глянуть код в правке к вопросу? Какие бы Вы внесли изменения. Я имею ввиду чисто структуру этого класса, может что-то Вы вынесли бы в отдельный класс. Просто очень хочется научиться писать красиво.

Comment: @Artik Лисенеры у вас сейчас - самая маленькая проблема) Там адское месиво из GUI-кода, бизнес-логики и даже доступ к данным. Это все должно быть вынесено в отдельные классы, если не пакеты.

Comment: @Artik Вот у вас есть классы, имплементирующие TableModel, по какой-то причине объявленные внутри фрейма. Это ваша view model.

Comment: @Artik Внутри она заполняется непосредственно с помощью SQL, хотя желательно поручить создавать модели и работать с базой отдельному объекту (Data Access Layer).

Comment: @Artik Кто может дать гарантию, что вам потом не понадобится мобильное приложение со своими собственными вью-моделями? Значит, должно быть какое-то наименьшее общее кратное - модели бизнес логики (BL entities). Кроме того, всякие рассчетные операции с моделями туда тоже можно унести. У нас получится Business Layer. Итого: у нас получилась трехзвенная архитектура: некоторое представление данных (VMs, класс окна, лисенеры и т.п.), бизнес-слой (бизнес-модели и рассчетные операции над ними) и DAL (связь с БД и маппинг данных из запросов в бизнес-модели и наоборот).

Comment: @ free_ze Блин, как всё сложно. Нет пока понимания даже того, что такое бизнес логика. Точнее как она должна быть выражена в коде. И если создавать отдельный объект для работы с БД для заполнения каждой TableModel, то не разрастётся ли проект до невменяемого количества классов и пакетов? Но всё равно, спасибо, что уделяете мне время. Буду курить дальше.

Comment: @ free_ze Вот-вот, мобильное приложение вполне может понадобиться. Начинаю понимать по крупицам. Сложно в голове собрать картину структуры проекта. Вы упомянули трехзвенную архитектуру. Каждое звено лучше помещать в свой пакет?

Comment: @Artik Начните с того, что вынесите свои вью-модели из класса формы в отдельные файлы. И пусть у вас будет какой-то сервис, который будет фабрикой для этих вью-моделей, автоматически работая с базой (чтобы в классе вью-моделей полностью отсутствовал SQL).

Comment: @Artik Что за класс Global? Если он умеет делать запросы, то стоило его назвать иначе. Мешать все в кучу не стоит, это же не javascript.

Comment: @ free_ze В класс Global я просто вынес некоторые статические методы, в том числе для работы с БД. Чтобы не прописывать каждый раз Connection'ы, Statement'ы, try с catch'ами написал статический метод, который принимает SQLQuery и возвращает двумерный массив выборки, с которым потом и работаю. Так нельзя?

Comment: @Artik Как я уже сказал, мешать все в кучу категорически нельзя, ибо мне, как читающему, "Global" не говорить ни о чем, кроме как о плохом дизайне.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44680/discussion-between-artik-and-free-ze).

Comment: Нашел книгу "Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений" Мартина Фаулера. Знакома, рекомендуете? Я вскользь просмотрел, многое из сказанного Вами там есть.